# Unable to ssh to google cloud instance which is created from the OVA

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have created a google cloud instance from the custom OVA by using the following command:

`gcloud beta compute instances import instance --source-uri=gs://abc/xyz.ova --os=centos-7`

In the VM which I used to create the OVA ssh is enabled on port 22.

Unfortunately, I am unable to ssh to the instance created. In gcp firewall ssh port 22 is enabled I am getting the following error while trying to ssh.

`ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].`

I couldn't get the exact reason. Any suggestion on this. Hope I am missing something here.

Comment: Please reboot your VM, collect full boot log via [serial port](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/viewing-serial-port-output#viewing_serial_port_output) and add it to your question.

Comment: Did you set up the user and SSH public key before creating the OVA image?

Comment: I have logged in via serial port. One issue I found is ip is not assigned to the VM(10.x.x.x). I have enabled dhcp in the OVA.

Comment: Have you solved your issue by enabling DHCP?

Comment: My issue is not resolved.

Comment: Okay, please provide more details to move forward: **1**. serial console boot log **2**. status of SSH daemon **3**. SSH error messages at the VM side **4**. status of the firewall at VM side and at the GCP side. **5**. other  troubleshooting steps you did so far by following the documentation [Troubleshooting SSH](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh).